# Adding additional vertical velocity in projectile motion Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, projectile

I have my point of projectile at some height above ground and my enemy(that are moving from right to left and towards the shooting point at horizontal axis) are at ground.The projectile motion that I have it shoots directly in downward motion at angle facing the enemy but I want the projectile to first go upwards and then shoot the enemy.

I have attached the snapshot below:

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class bullet : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    private Transform mytransform;
    public GameObject bulletprefab;
    public GameObject enemyprefab;
    private gamenemy e;

    public float firingAngle = 20;
    public float gravity = 9.8f;

    void Awake()
    {
        mytransform = transform;      
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    mytransform.LookAt(target);
        StartCoroutine (project ());
        //follow();
    }
    IEnumerator project()
    {    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        float target_Distance = Vector3.Distance(mytransform.position * target_Distance , target.position);
        // Calculate the velocity needed to throw the object to the target at specified angle.
        float projectile_Velocity = target_Distance / (Mathf.Sin(2 * target_Distance * Mathf.Deg2Rad) / gravity);


        // Extract the X  Y componenent of the velocity
        float Vx = Mathf.Sqrt(projectile_Velocity) * Mathf.Cos(target_Distance * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        float Vy = Mathf.Sqrt(projectile_Velocity) * Mathf.Sin( 1/target_Distance * Mathf.Deg2Rad);



        // Calculate flight time.
        float flightDuration = target_Distance / Vx;

        // Rotate projectile to face the target.
        mytransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - mytransform.position);

        float elapse_time = 0;

        while (elapse_time < flightDuration)
        {
            mytransform.Translate(0, (Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime, Vx * Time.deltaTime);

            elapse_time += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }
    }



    Snapshot of how it is with given code:
```

[image]

```
   This is how I want it to be:
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calculating the movement in your code, look at using a Rigidbody on your projectile. Then at the point of firing, [apply a force](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) relative to the initial trajectory (i.e direction the gun barrel is facing) and also have gravity affect your bullet.

[More on Rigidbodies](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html)

Comment: But I really am not looking to use AddForce, wanted to use something more directly implemented via code or more Generic

Comment: I agree with Dover8. You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Since you already have bullet prefab it is better to add a collider and a rigid body to it. Physics engine will automatically apply gravity force to the bullet's body. And you may handle collision in your custom script attached to bullet using [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).